# how to get callstack in a released application when use _set_purecall_handler

Tags: c++, c, windows, windbg

My code runs to "pure function call" error sometimes, so I use _set_purecall_handler to register a handler. In debug mode I can get full callstack use StackWalker, but in release mode StackWalker shows little usefull information. I try to use MiniDumpWriteDump and set ExceptionPointers = NULL. After crashed I got a dump file but vs can't debug it and show:
        The template specified cannot be found. Please check that the full path is correct.
Is there anyway to get information from a released application in such situation?

Comment: u can always provide debugging information

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I wanna get some debugging information as well..There are some limes do pure function call, and I want to find the place from the callstack when crashed.

Comment: If the default _purecall_handler displays a message box then don't call _set_purecall_handler. Instead, attach windbg to the process while the error message is being displayed, configure symbols, and then issue the `~*kb` windbg command to get the call stacks of all the threads. Then look at each call stack until you see one calling some variant of MessageBox.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, one can guess the method called by matching the vtable of the subclass with that of the abstract one - the vtable of an abstract class has a bunch of pure_call handlers for virtual functions with no implementation.

Everything you need to know regarding the method call is on the stack and in registers - just look at the disassembly of the call site, note the offset used to retrieve the function from vtable, dump the actual vtable of the deceased object - you can look it up by disassembling the code for constructor looking for `vftable's. Then a simple inspection with **dds** should give all the information you need to know which method was called (but not why the object is gone :o)

Comment: this application runs on other machines so when it crashing I can't get its stack and registers, it just pops up an error dialog without any useful information but just r6025..

Comment: that's a bummer - i'd advise to add some sort of unhandled exception handling either via something like a google breakpad or a service like [crash-server](http://www.crash-server.com)